# Suppes Axiomatic Set Theory Ch.2 Sec.2.3 Exercise 10

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following theorem concerning the existence of the universal set.

**Theorem**

$$\lnot(\exists A)(\forall x)(x\in A).$$

The axiom I used:

**Axiom Schema of Separation**

$$(\exists B)(\forall x)(x\in B\iff x\in A\land\varphi(x)).$$

Now here's my proof,

*proof.*

Suppose not. Then we have $A$ to be the universal set and $(\forall x)(x\in A)$. Now using the Axiom of Separation we can create a set by taking $\varphi(x):x\notin x$,

$$(\exists B)(\forall x)(x\in B\iff x\in A\land x\notin x).$$

Since $(\forall x)(x\in A)$ is always true, we then have

$$(\exists B)(\forall x)(x\in B\iff x\notin x).$$

Taking $x=B$ we infer:

$$B\in B\iff B\notin B,$$

a contradiction. Thus we conclude that $\lnot(\exists A)(\forall x)(x\in A)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The idea is correct but the phrasing of the last step "taking $x=B$,..." bothers me a bit. Slightly cleaner would be to assume that $B\in A$ and then consider when is $B\in B$ as well ($B\subseteq A$ by construction). Doing this gives you the desired contradiction $B\in B\iff B\notin B$ by definition of $B$, which implies that the assumption $B\in A$ was false and hence an universal set $A$ cannot exist. The same proof is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#cite_note-2)

Comment: Yes, it is correct: from $(∃B)(∀x)(x∈B⟺x∉x)$ we have $(∀x)(x∈B⟺x∉x)$. Now we instantiate the universal quantifier $(∀x)$ with $B$ itself (if the formula holds for every set, then it holds also for set $B$) and the result follows.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is correct. I have read a similar proof.

Incidentally, we may divide this proof into two parts. First we show a theorem that there is no such B, and then use it to show that there is no universal set.